# xlwings: How to loop through all tables in a workbook?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

How can I loop through all tables in a given workbook?

[I've found the code to loop through all Pivot Tables in a given worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788656/how-to-get-existing-pivot-table-names-and-modify-them-using-xlwings), but cannot find documentation for how to loop through all regular tables in a workbook.

```py
# This works:
for index, table in enumerate (sheet.api.PivotTables()):
    print(table)
# This does not work:
for index, table in enumerate (sheet.api.Tables()):
    print(table)

# Exception has occurred: com_error
# (-2147352570, 'Unknown name.', None, None)
# object has no attribute 'Tables'
```

Comment: Will ListObjects return more than just tables? If so, how can I check if the returned result is a table?

Comment: Thanks. I tried: `for list_object in sheet.api.ListObjects():`, but got the error "This object does not support enumeration"

Comment: Have you tried directly tables property on worksheet e.g.  import xlwings as xw 
 xw.books['Book1'].sheets[0].tables

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I overlooked such a simple solution, but that worked. `for table in sheet.tables:`